# Is the Eclipse web browser using the default OS browser?

Tags: eclipse, browser

Is the Eclipse web browser an instance of the SWT `Browser` class or is actually using one of the browser I have installed in the OS? i.e: Chrome or Firefox, if so, is there a way to determine what browser is using?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that if you are using a Linux distro, your default browser will be Mozilla Firefox. If you are using Windows the default is IE (this might have been changed in the current release of Eclipse). You can choose between internal and external browsers here:

[image]